# Stack Overflow blog lets posters have very heavy profile pictures

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

After noticing how slowly [the latest blog post's page loaded](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/12/new-kids-block-understanding-developers-entering-workforce-today/), and [seeing it pointed out](http://disq.us/p/1jiuwwd) in [multiple comments](http://disq.us/p/1jix91z), I can't help but wonder why SO Blog doesn't implement a profile picture downscaling thing, like any other sane blog in the world does. Even the main sites have a limit on file size.

OP's avatar in the latest post has 3339 x 3339 px resolution and a file size of 2.54 megabytes. That's not normal.

Comment: Cross-site duplication in [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/350592/2451726)

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4859/limit-author-image-size